# Create Controller Failure stating that the controller needs a parameterless public constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

> Create Controller Failure of type 'UserController'. Make sure that the
>   controller has a parameterless public constructor

Using AutoFac, I have registered UnitOfWork repository as below, also I'm pasting controller code and stack trace. Please assist. Unable to understand as why controller requires parameterless public costructor.

```
private static IContainer RegisterServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            //Register your Web API controllers.  
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            builder.RegisterType<UserContext>().As<DbContext>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<DBFactory>().As<IDBFactory>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(GenericRepo<>)).As(typeof(IGenericRepo<>)).InstancePerRequest();

            //Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.  
            Container = builder.Build();

            return Container;
        }  

private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitofwork;
        public UserController(IUnitOfWork uow)
        {
            _unitofwork = uow;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<UserDetail> UserData()
        {
            return _unitofwork.userDetail.GetAllUsers();
        }
```

### StackTrace

```
  at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.<Execute>b__0()
       at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator)
       at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
       at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.AutowiringParameter.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CanSupplyValue>b__0()
       at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
       at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
       at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
       at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType)
       at Autofac.Integration.WebApi.AutofacWebApiDependencyScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
       at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)
       at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
```

Controller:

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
  private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitofwork;
  public UserController(IUnitOfWork uow)
  {
      _unitofwork = uow;
  }

  [HttpGet]
  public IEnumerable<UserDetail> UserData()
  {
      return _unitofwork.userDetail.GetAllUsers();
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to check - you've actually registered AutoFac as the `DependencyResolver` as [per here](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#set-the-dependency-resolver)?

Comment: Have you registered `UserContorller` too?

Comment: No, I haven't. Where do i need to register? However UnitOfWork is registered.

Comment: Please share the Startup class

Comment: @MarcusHöglund do you mean AutofacWebapiConfig class? Don't have Startup.cs

Comment: @Aniruddha check the innerexception, usually when there are some dependency missing in the registration it gives this error ..

Comment: @Niladri InnerException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'UserApp.DAL.UnitOfWork' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'UserApp.Models.UserContext ctx' of constructor 'Void .ctor(UserApp.Models.UserContext)'.

Comment: @Aniruddha check if the DbContext is registered properly by using the dependencyresolver mentioned below .

Comment: @Niladri Yes it is: builder.RegisterType<UserContext>().As<DbContext>().InstancePerRequest();

Comment: @Aniruddha How are you passing the connection string to DbContext?

Comment: @Niladri No I did not.

Answer (score 3):

[As stated in the documentation, you need set the dependency resolver](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#set-the-dependency-resolver):

> After building your container pass it into a new instance of the AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver class. Attach the new resolver to your HttpConfiguration.DependencyResolver to let Web API know that it should locate services using the AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver. This is Autofac’s implementation of the IDependencyResolver interface.

```
var container = builder.Build();
config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

I can tell you aren't doing this because the stacktrace specifically states which resolver it's using to create controllers:

> System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)

Comment: This is how I've done it: config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Autofac.Integration.WebApi (Ver. 4.1) Autofac (Ver 4.8)

Comment: Can you update your code on where config.DependencyResolve is occuring.  Also add the controller that isn't working.

Comment: public static void Initialize(HttpConfiguration config, IContainer container)
        {
            config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
            
        }

Comment: public class UserController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitofwork;
        public UserController(IUnitOfWork uow)
        {
            _unitofwork = uow;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<UserDetail> UserData()
        {
            return _unitofwork.userDetail.GetAllUsers();
        }

Comment: Don't add code as comments, click the `Edit` button below your post and add it as code.

Answer (score -1):

Issue was due to wrong setup of IDbFactory.